# How can I remove datasets from a list based on conditon using lapply?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I have list of data frames for which I have to perform the same operations for each one. I currently do this with a `for loop` but it is too slow. I would like to use `lapply` instead. The operations which I need to perform is to check how many of the values in a date column in each dataset that are missing from a vector of dates.

The data have the following structure.

```
# the dates which are of interest
dates <- seq(as.Date("2020-02-01"), as.Date("2020-02-09"), by = "days")

# the list of data frames 
df_1 <- data.frame(seq(as.Date("2020-02-01"), as.Date("2020-02-09"), by = "days"), 1:9)
names(df_1) <- c("date", "value")    
df_2 <- data.frame(seq(as.Date("2020-02-01"), as.Date("2020-02-07"), by = "days"), 1:7)
names(df_2) <- c("date", "value")
df_list <- list(df_1, df_2)
```

The loop which is working but is too slow looks like this.

```
for (i in 1:length(df_list)) {
  # get range of dates in the data frame
  df_date_range <- unique(df_list[[i]][["date"]])

  # get range of dates that occur from the point of the beginning of the data frame
  dates_reduced <- dates[dates >= min(df_date_range)]

  # get the share of dates missing
  missing <- mean(!(dates_reduced %in% df_date_range))

  # remove data frames where the share of missing values are above 1 %
  if (missing > 0.1) {
    df_list[[i]] <- NULL
  }
}
```

I tried the following `lapply` approach.

```
# write function to use in lapply
clean <- function(data, date_range) {
  # get range of dates in the data frame
  df_date_range <- unique(data$date)

  # get range of dates that occur from the point of the beginning of the data frame
  dates_reduced <- date_range[date_range >= min(df_date_range)]

  # get the share of dates missing
  missing <- mean(!(dates_reduced %in% df_date_range))

  # remove data frames where the share of missing values are above 1 %
  if (missing > 0.1) {
    data <- NULL
  }
}

# apply the function to the list of data frames
new_df_list <- lapply(df_list, clean, date_range = dates)
```

This however only yields a list of NULLs. Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add `return(data)` as the last line of `clean()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we dont't **have** to explicitly specify return values in R it's always better to do so. Your problem illustrates this point! (R function implicitly return the result of the last expression, but that is not always what one would expect!):

Consider the following function:

```
no_explicit_return_value <- function() {
    some_non_NULL_value <- 10000
}
```

If we run:

```
test_value <- no_explicit_return_value()
test_value
```

We get back:

```
[1] 10000
```

Since the last expression returned 10000... so far all good!

Now, consider this function:

```
no_explicit_return_value <- function() {
    some_non_NULL_value <- 10000
    if (1000 < 4) {
        x <- NULL
    }
}
```

If we run:

```
test_value <- no_explicit_return_value()
test_value
```

We get back:

```
NULL
```

Not because the if clause evaluated to TRUE but because there **is no** return value from the if clause

The Solution:

```
clean <- function(data, date_range) {

    # get range of dates in the data frame
    df_date_range <- unique(data$date)

    # get range of dates that occur from the point of the beginning of the data frame
    dates_reduced <- date_range[date_range >= min(df_date_range)]

    # get the share of dates missing
    missing <- mean(!(dates_reduced %in% df_date_range))

    # remove data frames where the share of missing values are above 1 %
    if (missing > 0.1) {
        data <- NULL
    }

    return(data)
}

# apply the function to the list of data frames
new_df_list <- lapply(df_list, clean, date_range = dates)

new_df_list
```

Returns:

```
[[1]]
date value
1 2020-02-01     1
2 2020-02-02     2
3 2020-02-03     3
4 2020-02-04     4
5 2020-02-05     5
6 2020-02-06     6
7 2020-02-07     7
8 2020-02-08     8
9 2020-02-09     9

[[2]]
NULL
```